# location.reload() is continuously refreshing my page

Tags: javascript, php

I want the page to reload when I delete an item from the table of this page so I've used the "location.reload();" method for this but page refresh is infinitely looping when I press delete(anchor tag).

This is for MySQL server, php5. In the past, I’ve tried on existing servers and always seem to end up having problem..

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{ ?> <div id = "detele"> <?php
  $del = $_GET['id'];
  $query = "DELETE FROM student WHERE id =  '$del'";
  $conn->query($query);
echo 
"<script>
  location.reload();
</script>";
```

I want the page to reload once I've clicked on delete but its not stopping.

Comment: You reload the same URL so the parameter `$_GET['id']` is still there, this is normal then, wether there is an element to delete or not, the script is added

Comment: What should i do then ?

Comment: also you shouldn't be deleting data on a GET request. Use POST instead.

Comment: First of all, separate your backend logic from your frontend HTML. There's no point in mixing that PHP code into that HTML. Put the PHP at the very top of the file. Then, instead of a Javascript reload, *redirect* to another page, presumably without the `?id=...`, using `header('Location: ...')`.

Comment: Should never directly use user input in database queries as in the delete command, that is just asking for a student to try some SQL injection techniques. Should always sanitise input to be used in SQL queries whether in your own code, or using PHP PDO library.

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
<?php
header('location:your_page.php');
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, but that probably won't work in OP's code as is…

Comment: just use it and don't add get parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are getting infinite loop because when your page reloads, it always enters the if block

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
```

because it was never unset

you should use the `unset` function to remove that `id` parameter from your request object, something like below

```php
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{ ?> <div id = "detele"> <?php
  $del = $_GET['id'];
  $query = "DELETE FROM student WHERE id =  '$del'";
  $conn->query($query);
  unset($_GET['id']);
echo 
"<script>
  window.location.href = 'your php page here.php';
</script>";
```

Comment: That won't get rid of the `?id=...` already in the browser's URL.

Comment: still same problem: page refresh is infinitely looping

Comment: @AnssSheikh sorry, deceze was right, I corrected my answer

Comment: no problem man :D keep up the coding! :D and try using modern php frameworks and code patterns :D

Comment: hmm Ok Thanks bro.. BTW I am new in web backend.. that's why working on core php ^_^